# Shell error with emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am trying to build my first Android app. I get the below error message (*See Original Error Message*) when trying to run my emulator.

### Question

> **What is the error message telling me? And what should I do next to fix it?**

I've already tried running various versions of the following shell command:

```
pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.template.gotouch.androidtemplate"
```

Like:

```
pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.template.gotouch.androidtemplate"
npm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.template.gotouch.androidtemplate"
sudo pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.template.gotouch.androidtemplate"
sudo npm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.template.gotouch.androidtemplate"
```

Original Error Message

```
Target device: Nexus_5_API_22 [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
  local path: /Users/thisuser/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidTemplate/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
  remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.template.gotouch.androidtemplate
Installing com.template.gotouch.androidtemplate
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.template.gotouch.androidtemplate"
Error: Could not access the Package Manager. Is the system running?
```

So what to try next?

Comment: To whom it may concern: Why the downvote? Please explain.

Comment: I don't see a reason for a downvote either, other than that tagging it as a "shell" question seems to be inappropriate here. Doesn't look like a shell issue to me. Since I am not an expert in Android, I can't help here either...